# Colour on a image changes on different on machines

Tags: html, css, macos, web-safe-colors

This might not strictly be a coding question, but its related so i'll post it up anyway.

I built a website a year ago and never had any problems. I've recently moved to Mac and I've started noticing small colour related issues between my Macbook and my Pro.

In the header there's a background image aligned top right. The background colour of the header matches the image to show a smooth fade from image to background colour. On my Mac Pro it looks fine, on my Macbook Air the image is slightly darker.

I've attached a screenshot of the background image below. You should see a quite obvious swap from background color to background image.

In photoshop the Hex of the background color and image fade are exactly the same.

Does anyone know why this this happens?

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZJ6B.png

Comment: it should be a OS issue!

Comment: What image format did you save the graphic out with, and how (export/save as)?

Comment: Seems to have fixed itself now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be more to do with your screen rather than a coding issue. You will find that all screens display images slightly differently. In fact, the image you have posted will look different to me now, than it does on either of your machines. Often the difference is slight. This can be to do with different display technologies (LCD, CRT etc) or just the slight differences in manufacture.

Comment: Hmm, then why when I save the image and place it in photoshop does it have a different hex code than the screenshot?

Comment: When I save the image and use the eyedropper to get the hex, it is #557e54. When I screenshot the page and eyedrop the saved screenshot it is #438355